# Failed to run Selenoid on MacOS

Tags: macos, selenoid

My configuration:

- Selenoid Configuration Manager 1.8.5
- Docker Desktop 4.26.1 with Docker Engine 24.0.7

When I run

```
$ ./cm selenoid start --vnc
```

I get

```
Failed to initialize: [can not access Docker: make sure you have Docker installed and current user has access permissions]
```

`docker ps` works well:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

Comment: Do you have M1 or x86 Mac OS?

Comment: I have x86 Mac OS